# How to Remove one file of selected files from dynamic generated input file control in a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDrev.jpg)I have a html table where I am adding row dynamically, I have 3 columns in this table First one is drop-down list, 2nd one is dynamically generated input file button , and 3rd column is for Delete the row. I have set "multiple" type for input file control to choose multiple files along with "Remove" hyperlink to remove a specific file if end user want , I am able to remove file from list but actually file is not removing from input file control ,  I can see file count is not decreasing even after remove the specif file from list. I have also attached a screen shot, 
I am able to remove file list but file is not removing from input file control
but file is not removing from input file control

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this should include what you code looks like and the things you have tried to solve your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like `document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').value = null` when you click remove?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the built in input use a label with a hidden input inside you will also nee to handle your files from the change event manually instead of using serialize on a form you will create a `new FormData()` and append the files to it along with any other data.

```js
var Files = [];
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('input#files').on('change', (e)=>{
    let files = e.target.files;
    for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
      let file = files[i];
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.id = Files.length;
      $(div).append(`${file.name} <span class="delete-file" data-id="${Files.length}">X</span>`);
      $('div.files-container').append(div);
      Files.push(file);
      updateLabel();
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', 'span.delete-file', function(e){
    let id = $(this).data('id');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    Files.splice(id, 1);
    updateLabel();
  });
});


function updateLabel() {
  let text = 'Select Files';
  if(Files.length > 1) text = `${Files.length} Files`;
  else if(Files.length > 0) text = `${Files.length} File`;
  $('#files-count').html(text);
}
```

```css
label.custom-input{
display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 150px;
}

label.custom-input input{
  display: none;
  
 }
 
.files-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px;
}

.files-container div{
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

span.delete-file{
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="files" class="custom-input">
    <input id="files" type="file" multiple>
    <span id="files-count">Select Files</span>
</label>
<div class="files-container">

</div>
```